# How can I distribute my table columns in more than one class in Spring Boot while creating REST API to store data in Database?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, rest, jpa, spring-data-jpa

**DATABASE:** PostgreSQL

My table (for e.g.):
**TABLE NAME:** MALL.

**COLUMNS:**
*mall_id,
mall_name,
mallmanager_name,
email,
mobile_no,
address_1,
address_2,
address_3,
pin,
state,
country*

I want to put data in my table using REST API in Spring Boot (Spring Tool Suite app). For this, I can create a single Entity class where I can declare all my columns in it and then create a REST API that does the job.

*`But I want to do it differently.`*

As you can see the columns, I want to create 3 separate classes in one single entity package; one class will be say MALL class which will hold only *mall_id* and *mall_name* columns AND also it should autowire two other classes (explained next), second class which will be say BasicDetails class which will contain *mallmanager_name, email* and *mobile_no* (and this class gets autowired in Mall class as said earlier) and third class which will be say AddressDetails class which will contain *address_1, address_2, address_3, pin, state* and *country* (and this class also gets autowired in Mall class as said earlier).

So, now I can have three separate classes (where Mall is the main class which has its own 2 columns and rest columns are divided into 2 separate classes and autowired in this class) in one package say
**com.mall.entity**.

**Please guide me how should I do this.**

Comment: For each table define a separate entity. If needed, define relations between entities. Before asking further questions please show what have you already done, show your code. Until then I suggest to close the question.

Comment: As I said, I have only one table with many columns. And I have done making the api. But read "But I want to do it differently" part please.

Comment: Put the 1st set of attributes into the 1st class, declare the 2nd and 3rd as @Embedded.

Comment: I did it by autowired those 2 classes in first class. And then in creation of restapi, in serviceImpl class, I autowired all three classes and get the values of each field (of all three classes) and set it in the entity class. This is how I did.